# Trigger a sound when player picks up object

Tags: c#, audio, unity-game-engine, triggers

I'm having trouble with sound triggering. The script below is attached to a coin prefab object with an AudioSource component and sound clip attached. Everything is working except there is no sound. What am I doing wrong?

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class CoinPickup : MonoBehaviour {

    void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)  // other is a reference to the other trigger collider we have touched
    {
        if (other.gameObject.CompareTag ("Player"))
        {
            gameObject.SetActive (false);
            Debug.Log ("Sound should trigger here.");

            coinSound = gameObject.GetComponent<AudioSource>();
            coinSound.Play();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is your `AudioListener` close enough to the object in order to hear the coin sound? Also, try deactivating `gameObject` only after the sound has played.

Comment: When I check the box 'Play On Awake' the sound plays as soon as the game starts, so I know the sound works. It's just not playing when my player object collides with the coin object.

Comment: All right. I think the issue is that you can't play a sound on a deactivated `GameObject`. Your options are to either delay the `SetActive (false)` for the duration of `coinSound`, or have a different `GameObject` play `coinSound` instead. Let me know if you need a solution posted as an answer.

Comment: The suspicions of @Serlite are correct. You won't hear the sound if you disable it prior to triggering the sound to play. Look into using the PlayClipAtPoint method. May work wondering for this exact case scenario

Comment: @ejsd1989, so the PlayClipAtPoint method work even if the object is disabled?

Comment: It should behave such that it will instantiate the audio source to play once at the transform location. Then it will destroy and clean it up.

Answer (score 0):

Might not be what you are looking for, but I usually instantiate sounds like this: (I have no access to Unity at the moment, so bare with)

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class CoinPickup : MonoBehaviour 
{
    public AudioSource coinSound; //set in inspector    

    void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)  // other is a reference to the other trigger collider we have touched
    {
        if (other.gameObject.tag == "Player") //or you could do other.gameObject.name == "Player"
        {
            coinSound.Play(); //play the coin sound
            Destroy(gameobject); // destroy our coin, it has been picked up!
        }
    }
}
```

I'm not sure, but I don't think you can play sounds on a de-activated gameObject.

This way should play the sound when your player comes into contact with your coin, at which point it will play your sound, and the coin will then destroy itself.

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

Switch the script.  So instead of triggering when the coin hits the player, make it so that when the player hits the coin and then attach that script to the player.

Also, make it an `AudioClip` and add an `AudioSource` to the `Player`

```
public AudioClip coinSound; //set in inspector    

void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)  // other is a reference to the other trigger collider we have touched
{
    if (other.gameObject.tag == "Coin") 
    {
        coinSound.Play(); //play the coin sound
    }
}
```